# Transform multiple arrays of objects into a single object

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

Issue: There are untyped objects returned with over 100 possible different keys.
I want to transform all of the error objects, regardless of type, into a single object.

```js
const input = [
    {
        "type":"cat",
        "errors":[
            {
                "keyA":"This is wrong!",
                "keyB":"This is more wrong!!",
                "keyC":"...horrible, just horrible"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type":"dog",
        "errors":[
            {
                "key1":"whoops",
                "key2":"somebody has a typo"
            },
            {
                "keyX":"umm...really?",
                "keyY":"when did it start raining?"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

expected output =

```js
            {
                "keyA":"This is wrong!",
                "keyB":"This is more wrong!!",
                "keyC":"...horrible, just horrible",
                "key1":"whoops",
                "key2":"somebody has a typo",
                "keyX":"umm...really?",
                "keyY":"when did it start raining?"
            }
```

My current attempt (which works) looks like this. However I think that it may not need to reduce calls. Is there a more simple approach?

```js
const returnVal = val.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    return ([...acc.errors, ...curr.errors] as any).reduce((a: any, c: any) => ({...a, ...c}), {});
});
```

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ...input.flatMap(x => x.errors))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.flatMap()` get an array of objects, and then merge them to a single object by spreading into `Object.assign()`:

```js
const input = [{"type":"cat","errors":[{"keyA":"This is wrong!","keyB":"This is more wrong!!","keyC":"...horrible, just horrible"}]},{"type":"dog","errors":[{"key1":"whoops","key2":"somebody has a typo"},{"keyX":"umm...really?","keyY":"when did it start raining?"}]}]

const result = Object.assign({}, ...input.flatMap(o => o.errors))

console.log(result)
```

With TS, you'll need to give a general type to the object, because the `errors` object has random properties ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FcwHkBGAVhAmMgN4BQyNyYAnhhAFzIDOYUoA5gNzW1oUAPZQ2rAEolRAEwA8HLiG4Aadpx4A+ANoBdSgF9KlBMJAdkobGFbprBYqT3IAvMm3kARAyafmnhDgwTxVPIVE2Pw9PAGsIegBBP08AFQALYDZLLIB3EWUAQhDY+IAhZPTM7OQAW1EUPLNuAqLQuPoAYWSAOl600S58ABsINUIsC36oQZHPA10DFS8fCGSZYW5i8LEor3aARmSc-uEMSLb4gCZktmEaiHxhGXpkNLgsuDpGYTmlkvoABrJLA1Gq9bpQCBwIZDegAfmK7QAmkc0hAQMgZMAZJYyBw4FAyFA4KAeAj5vNjKZzESIGwsEMyG4HCQwN13mxgNwQAAKciLZDgqw4bowIZBACycAwPOErk0yGE3W2bAAlKqqWZbiNukMNjzIfTGaqgA)):

```
interface InputObject {
  type: string;
  errors: Record<string, string>[]
}

const input: InputObject[] = [{"type":"cat","errors":[{"keyA":"This is wrong!","keyB":"This is more wrong!!","keyC":"...horrible, just horrible"}]},{"type":"dog","errors":[{"key1":"whoops","key2":"somebody has a typo"},{"keyX":"umm...really?","keyY":"when did it start raining?"}]}]

const result = Object.assign({}, ...input.flatMap(o => o.errors))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: The cast to `Object` is not necessary. In any case, `Object` should not be used as a type anyways.

Comment: Good catch. Removed.